# "Failed to generate image" when using custom Discord bot that uses DALL-E to generate images

Tags: python, discord, artificial-intelligence, openai-api

I am trying to build a Discord bot that takes the /create and generates images using the OpenAI DALL-E model, based on the user's input. However, after the bot prompts the message "What text would you like to generate an image for?", I input the text, but I get the error "Failed to generate image". What can I do? Thank you!

This is code that functions:

```
import os
import json
import requests

import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@bot.command(name='create')
async def create_image(ctx):
    await ctx.send("What text would you like to generate an image for?")

    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel

    try:
        text = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=60.0)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send("Timed out, please try again.")
        return

    text = text.content

    api_key = os.environ.get("API_KEY")

    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    data = """
    {
        """
    data += f'"model": "image-alpha-001",'
    data += f'"prompt": "{text}",'
    data += """
        "num_images":1,
        "size":"1024x1024",
        "response_format":"url"
    }
    """

    resp = requests.post(
        "https://api.openai.com/v1/images/generations",
        headers=headers,
        data=data,
        auth=("", api_key),
    )

    if resp.status_code != 200:
        await ctx.send("Failed to generate image.")
        return

    response_text = json.loads(resp.text)
    image_url = response_text['data'][0]['url']

    await ctx.send(image_url)

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: Well, you should probably look at what `resp.text` is if the status code is not 200...

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I used response.status_code and response.text and got this: 405
{
  "error": {
    "code": null,
    "message": "Not allowed to GET on /v1/images/generations. (HINT: Perhaps you meant to use a different HTTP method?)",
    "param": null,
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}